# 'initializing' error in VS2010 while initializing an array

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I need to assign an array of 6 arrays and it's from type `set[maxSetLength]`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxSetLength 129

typedef short int set[maxSetLength]; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
int i;
set a={0},b={0},c={0},d={0},e={0},f={0}; // Assigning 6 Sets (Arrays) initialized by zeros
set sets[6]={a,b,c,d,e,f}; //Inserting All Sets into one Array (Array Of Arrays)
}
```

In CodeBlocks it compiles with no errors , in VS2010 it doesn't and these are the errors:

6 times

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'set' to 'short'
```

6 times

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "short *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "short"
```

12 Errors overall

Comment: `test.c:1:1: error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory`.  If you're going to ask questions that are in no way Windows-specific please remove all Windowsisms from your code before posting.

Comment: @Zack what do you mean Windowssisms ? this is how the teacher taught me

Comment: Your teacher is incompetent then.

Comment: @Zack: His teacher is incompetent because they are using VS?  Get over yourself.  VS adds a precompiled header to many project types by default, yeesh.  Stop adding useless comments intended only to brow beat a beginner.

Comment: Anyhow, actual serious advice: download MSVC 2012 and try that.  I  suspect you are trying to make use of a C++11 feature that CodeBlocks implements and MSVC 2010 (which is older) doesn't.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, handing out Windows-specific skeleton code without telling the students that you are doing so -- especially when the program is otherwise entirely standard -- qualifies as incompetence in my book.

Comment: @Zack: Well I suppose it's a good thing that no one cares to read your book.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pointers (they are tricky in C). Try the following code (I've added some debug, so change it back to 0's):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maxSetLength 129

typedef short int set[maxSetLength]; 

main()
{

int i;
set a={55},b={0},c={0},d={0},e={0},f={66}; // Assigning 6 Sets (Arrays) initialized by zeros
set sets[6]={*a,*b,*c,*d,*e,*f};

printf("%d\n", sets[0][0]);   // should be 55
printf("%d\n", sets[0][5]);   // should be 66

}
```

Comment: Now with your way i get 6 errors instead of 12,
ERROR 6 Times:
`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'set' to 'short'`

Comment: Not sure who downvoted - but that C code is a hack of his code to remove the compile errors. Tested on 3 different gcc compilers to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
set a={0},b={0},c={0},d={0},e={0},f={0}; // Assigning 6 Sets (Arrays) initialized by zeros
set *sets[6]={&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f}; //Inserting All Sets into one Array (Array Of Arrays)
```

Comment: It works but i must change all the project parameters for that , so i still want it like it worked on CodeBlocks

Comment: @GabourX i think that it should do to run once the appropriate function instead.